# A question about generated sigma-algebra in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

The class $\mathscr{S}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a semi-algebra,and $\sigma(\mathscr{S})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra  generated by $\mathscr{S}$.
Here is a proposition:if $\Omega$ is countable,then $$\sigma(\mathscr{S})=\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n:\forall n\geqslant1,A_n\in\mathscr{S}\}.$$
I want to know whether the proposition is right?If the proposition is right could you please provide me a proof of it.Thank you!

Comment: What does the sum symbol stand for?

Comment: The sum symbol stands for the merge of mutually disjoint sets.

Comment: What is the merge of sets? Do you refer to the union?

Comment: Yeah,sorry ,I mean the union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your proposition does not hold.

Consider the semi-algebra over $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ given by:

$\mathbb{N}$, $\emptyset$, {any single even number in $\mathbb{N}$}, $\mathbb{N}-$any finite number of even numbers in $\mathbb{N}$

The set of all odd numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ should belong to the generated $\sigma$-algebra (as the countable intersection of the sets $E_{n}=$[$\mathbb{N}-$all even numbers in $[-n;n]$]) but cannot be written as a countable union of sets belonging to the semi-algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.And I get it now.